# Increasing the speed of displaying the form

Tags: c#, .net, performance, winforms, show

I am currently working on a project where the display speed of the forms is very slow when called.

In order to increase the speed of displaying the forms, I did the following activities.

1. Inside the program, I defined a static class named 'Global' and inside that static class I defined my static and public forms.

   > ```
   > static partial class Global
   > {
   > //............................................................
   > public static Frm_Main MainForm;
   > public static Frm_Doing MainDoing;
   > public static Frm_MainsTimer MainsTimer;
   > }
   > ```
2. Then I wrote an initialization routine inside the program, I make a sample of the forms like this .

> ```
> public static void Initialize_Forms()
> {
> Global.MainForm = new Frm_Main();
> Global.MainDoing = new Frm_Doing();
> Global.MainEvents = new Frm_MainsTimer();
> }
> ```

3. Then I called it when I wanted. Because the definition and construction of the form had been done, there was no need to do these things at the time of calling, so the speed of displaying the forms increased greatly. Like this :

> `Global.MainsTimer.Show();`

But...
Again, the speed of displaying the forms is not good.

The first time a form is found on the screen. The speed of its appearance is low, but it will appear at a much higher speed in the following times.

what is the reason ?
Can I display the form invisible once at the beginning of the program and display the form normally at later times?

Do you know a solution to increase the speed of displaying the form on the screen?

Comment: Have you done any profiling of the application to determine the actual bottleneck?  What specific *identified* bottleneck were you addressing when creating those "global" form instances?  So far it sounds like all efforts have been based on only guesses, and that you're just asking for more guesses.  Debugging observations will always be more valuable than random guesses.

Comment: Find and fix the code that causes the delays. You didn't post any form initialization code so we can't help. Creating global instances of the forms creates *more* problems because you now have to clean up the data they display when you hide and show them again. You can easily end up with forms that show stale data

Comment: You have to be careful not to create memory leaks this way. As the others said, first try to find out on each form what the delay is caused by and optimize them one by one. If you still have issues with the loading time, you can create a splash screen during which the forms are loaded invisibly. On application exit, make sure all the memory is released by removing all references and calling the garbage collector `GC.Collect();`

Comment: I have a lot of DataGridViews that are displayed inside a Flow layout panel these data are lists of files and folders and subfolders.

Comment: If you have many DataGridViews make sure they aren't pulling any data from your database if you want to keep them hidden anyway. That can slow it down too. Only refresh the data right before you intend to make it visible.